# How to toggle attributes of elements created on child components that were generated after a form submission

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code where someone can add names into a an array of objects. I can't get to toggle one of the elements created after submission.

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import User from './User';



 class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list:list,
      searchTerm:'',
      userInputValue:'',
      users:[],
     };

  }

  userUpdateMethod = e =>
    this.setState({
      userInputValue:e.target.value
    });

  newUserSubmitHandler = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      users: this.state.users.concat([{name:this.state.userInputValue,isConfirmed:false}]),
      userInputValue:""
    });
}

  toggleAttendance = () =>{
  const toggleConfirmed = this.state.users.isConfirmed;
    this.setState({
      users:!toggleConfirmed
    });
    }


  render() {
    const {searchTerm, list} =this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">


        <User
          a = {this.state.userInputValue}
          b = {this.userUpdateMethod}
          c = {this.newUserSubmitHandler}
          d = {this.state.users}
          e = {this.toggleAttendance}
        />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The function that I can get to work is toggleAttendance and it resides on the User component

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

      const User = props =>

      <div>
        <h2>User Component</h2>
        <form onSubmit={props.c}>
          <input type="text" onChange={props.b} value = {props.a}/>
          <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> Submit</button>
        </form>

        <div>The follwowing will be attending:{props.d.map((user,index) =>
          <div> {user.name} is {user.isConfirmed? "coming":"not coming"}
          <button onClick={()=>props.e(index)}>toggle attendance</button>
          </div>
        )}
        </div>
      </div>;


export default User;
```

I have tried several ways to update the toggleAttendance method from the main App component but with no luck

Comment: Do  you have a jsfiddle or jsbin etc. link that people can fix? (and can you add that to your post, not add it as comment?)

Comment: You pass an index to `toggleAttendance` but never use it. You set `this.state.users` to an array but then try to access a property: `this.state.users.isConfirmed`.

Comment: Figured it out
 toggleAttendance = (index) =>{
  const toggleConfirmed = this.state.users;
  toggleConfirmed[index].isConfirmed =!toggleConfirmed[index].isConfirmed
    this.setState({
      users:toggleConfirmed
    });
    }